# Collision2D is not called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I know that this is a fairly regular question however having tried the solutions provided I have not been having much luck. Trying to get some object to collide in unity which worked, however the OnCollision2d call is not being made after they collide. Hoping to get some help on why this is happening.

The two classes provided here

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Missile: MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool dead = false, hostile = true;
    public float speed = 30,  rotatingSpeed= 200;
    public GameObject target;

    private BoxCollider2D bc;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private GameObject go;

    public Missile() { Debug.Log("Constructed"); }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("Missile Launched");

        go     = new GameObject("Missile");
        go.tag = "Missile";
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ship");

        rb = go.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        sr = go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        bc = go.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        bc.size = new Vector2(2f, 2f);

        //bc.isTrigger = true;
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0, 11);
        sr.sprite = SpriteManager.current.GetSprite("Ships", "missile1");
    }
    private void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        //sr.sprite = SpriteManager.current.GetSprite("Missiles", "missile1");
        //Debug.Log(target);
        if (!target) return;

        var point2Target = (Vector2) go.transform.position - (Vector2) target.transform.position;
        point2Target.Normalize();

        float value = Vector3.Cross(point2Target, go.transform.right).z;
        rb.angularVelocity = rotatingSpeed * value;
        //Vector2 lastVel = rb.velocity;
        rb.velocity = go.transform.right * speed;
        //rb.AddForce(go.transform.right * speed);
    }
    public void setPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,11);
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
        Destroy (go, 0.02f);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
        Destroy (go, 0.02f);
    }
}
```

And the second class

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Ship: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int hull  = 100, type = 1;
    public bool dead = false;
    public float speed = 5, rotatingSpeed= 200;
    public GameObject target;

    private BoxCollider2D bc;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sr;
    private GameObject go;

    public Ship() { Debug.Log("Constructor"); }
    private void OnEnable() 
    {
        Debug.Log("Ship Built");
        go = new GameObject("Ship");
        go.tag = "Ship";
        //target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        rb = go.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        sr = go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        bc = go.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        bc.size = new Vector2(2f, 2f);;
        bc.isTrigger = true;
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,11);
        sr.sprite = SpriteManager.current.GetSprite("Ships", "ship2");
        //sr.sprite.transform.localScale = anyWidth;
        //sr.sprite = SpriteManager.current.GetSprite("Missiles", "missile1");
    }
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        //Debug.Log(target);        
        GameObject[] missiles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Missile");
        /*foreach (GameObject missile in missiles)
        {
            Vector2 point2Target = ((Vector2)go.transform.position - (Vector2) missile.transform.position);
            if(point2Target.magnitude < 50)
            {
                point2Target.Normalize();
                Flak flak = gameObject.AddComponent<Flak>();
                flak.setPosition(go.transform.position);
                point2Target.x = point2Target.x * -1;
                point2Target.y = point2Target.y * -1;
                flak.setVelocity(point2Target * 50);
                break;
            }
        }*/
        if (target != null) 
        {
            var point2Target = (Vector2) go.transform.position - (Vector2) target.transform.position;
            point2Target.Normalize();

            float value = Vector3.Cross(point2Target, go.transform.right).z;
            rb.angularVelocity = rotatingSpeed * value;
            rb.velocity = go.transform.right * speed;
            //Vector2 lastVel = rb.velocity;
            //rb.AddForce(go.transform.right * speed;);
        }
    }
    public void setPosition(int x, int y) { go.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,11); }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
        Destroy (go, 0.02f);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");
        Destroy (go, 0.02f);
    }
}
```

and finally the invoking

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp("i")) 
{
    var ship = gameObject.AddComponent<Ship>();
    ship.setPosition((int)currFramePosition.x, (int)currFramePosition.y);
}
if (Input.GetKeyUp("v"))
{
    var missile = gameObject.AddComponent<Missile>();
    missile.setPosition((int)currFramePosition.x, (int)currFramePosition.y);
    Debug.Log(missile);
}
```

Some help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I dont see an `OnCollisionEnter2D`... only `OnTriggerEnter2D`...  The only problem I see here though is you are using `OnCollisionEnter` ( which is a 3d collision event) with what looks like an object with a 2D collider(cant mix 2D Colliders with 3D collisions several of the answers here explain that...)

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the current state. while using OnCollisionEnter2D it still does not work.

Comment: how would `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision)` be called when it isnt an actual event?  should be `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)`

Comment: Implemented that as well. Still does not work. I believe the issue is with the gameObject implementation.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I cannot solve a problem if I don't have your actual code, I've pointed out 2 mistakes in it already, that you claim you have already tried.  So the problem then lies in either the settings of these components on the actual object which I would need a screenshot of, or an issue in your collision matrix.

Comment: Also, with a GameObject with a rigidbody, you should never set the position yourself in an update(or FixedUpdate) use the provide functions on Rigidbody to adjust your objects position.